# find a sequence of values within a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am looking for the best way to find a sequence of values of varying lengths within a longer pandas Series. For example, I have the values `[92.6, 92.7, 92.9]` (but could also be length 2 or 5) and would like to find all the cases where this exact sequence occurs within the longer Series

```
s = pd.Series([92.6,92.7,92.9,24.2,24.3,25.1,24.9,25.1,24.9,97.6,94.5,1.0,92.6,92.7,92.9,97.9,96.8,96.4,92.8,92.8,93.1,89.5,89.6])
```

(actual series is approx length 1000).

In this example the correct result should be indices `0,1,2` and `12,13,14`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) to identify the last row of each stretch:

```
target = [92.6, 92.7, 92.9]

m = s.rolling(len(target)).apply(lambda x: x.eq(target).all())
out = m[m.eq(1)].index
```

Output: `[2, 14]`

For all indices:

```
out = [x for end in m[m.eq(1)].index for x in range(end-len(target)+1, end+1)]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 12, 13, 14]
```

Alternatively, using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)'s [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html), giving the starting indices:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

out = np.where((swv(s, len(target)) == target).all(axis=1))[0]
```

Output: `array([ 0, 12])`

For all indices:

```
out2 = (np.linspace(out[:,None], out[:,None]+len(target)-1, len(target))
          .ravel('F').astype(int)
        )
```

Output: `array([ 0,  1,  2, 12, 13, 14])`